# I get error when I setup react-alert with my react app Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-component

I got this error  :

```
react-dom.development.js:14748 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in Unknown (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App
    in Provider
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType
```

this is my Alerts component

```
import React, { Component , Fragment} from 'react'
import { withAlert } from "react-alert";
export class Alerts extends Component {

        componentDidMount(){
            this.props.alert.show("it worked");
        }


    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>

            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default withAlert(Alerts);
```

and this is my App.js

```
import React ,{ Component, Fragment }  from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {Provider as AlertProvider} from 'react-alert';
import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Leads from './components/leads';
import AddLead from './components/AddLead';
import  Alerts from './components/Alerts'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


const alertOptions = {
    timeout:3000,
    position:"top center"
}

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
                <Fragment>
                    <Header/>
                    <Alerts/>
                    <Leads/>
                    <AddLead/>
                </Fragment>
                </AlertProvider>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default App;
render(<Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

my errors reducer :

```
import { GET_ERRORS } from '../actions/Types';


const initialState = {
    msg: {},
    status:null
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_ERRORS:
            return {
                msg:action.payload.msg,
                status:action.payload.status
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line of Alert component from `export default withAlert(Alerts);` to
`export default withAlert()(Alerts);` according to [react-alert docs](https://github.com/schiehll/react-alert).